# mvc/jquery change label text onSuccess/Failure

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I need some help on this problem. I have modal dialog that pops up from a link of a search results. I want to change the label text in the modal dialog after an Ajax call. The text from the label (id="textlabel") only change once. After that it doesn't change at all. I've put an alert on the onSuccess method and it does show the appending text every time the dialog is open and clicked submit, but the label text does not get updated.

Thanks for the help.

```
<label id="textlabel" >...</label>
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Add", "Add", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "ID", OnSuccess = "onSuccess", OnFailure = "onFailure" }))
{ ... }


<script>     
function OnSuccess() {
    var lbl = $('#textlabel').text();
    $('#textlabel').text(lbl + "Sucess");
    alert(lbl + "Sucess");
}

function OnFailure() {
    var lbl = $('#textlabel').text();
    $('#textlabel').text(lbl + "Fail");
    alert(lbl + "Fail");
}
```

Comment: use $('#textlabel').val() instead of $('#textlabel').text()

Comment: I used  $('#textlabel').val() and it doesn't even change the label text at all. But if I use my old $('#textlabel').text() it change the label text 1 time and that's it. Weird...

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
function OnSuccess() {
    var lbl = $('#textlabel').text();
    $('#textlabel').empty().append(lbl + " success");
    alert(lbl + "Sucess");
}
```

Comment: Somehow that still does not clear out the label text. It still appends to show "... success success Success" in the alert window. The label still doesn't show the "... success success Success"

Comment: I searched my whole project for "textlabel" and it's only in my View where I have it to show up in the dialog. The weird thing is that why would the label text changed for the first time when I click submit and not after that? Any other idea?